# Routing to error channel but getting "Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel"

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have to alter an existing flow in Spring Integration (4.3.12, Java DSL). There is an existing SOAP call, after that I have to insert a new SOAP call (it is done) and if the existing SOAP call wasn't successful then the new SOAP call has to be skipped (it is where I have problems). In the flow below the `acmePreCompEnricher` is the existing call and the `ifMLCallRequiredEnricher` is the new one.

```
    return flow -> flow.channel(ORCH_REQUEST_INPUT)
            .<HomeRequest, HomeModel>transform(requestToModelTransformer)
            ...
            // 
            .enrich(this::acmePreCompRequestEnricher)
            .enrich(this::acmePreCompEnricher)
            .handle(this.acmePreCompResponseValidator())
            // 
            .enrich(this::ifMLCallRequiredEnricher)
            // 
            .enrich(this::acmeRequestEnricher)
            .enrich(this::acmeEnricher)
            ...
```

So in the `acmePreCompEnricher` I set the error channel that will handle the error:

```
   ContentEnricher contentEnricher = enricherSpec
            .requestPayload(Message::getPayload)
            .requestChannel(acmePreCompEnrichmentInputChannel())
            .replyChannel(acmePreCompEnrichmentOutputChannel())
            .get();
   contentEnricher.setErrorChannel(skipMLInputChannel());

   @Bean(name = "skip.ml.input")
   public MessageChannel skipMLInputChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
   }
```

In case of SOAP fault the message will go to the following flow:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow processSkipML() {
    return flow -> flow.channel("skip.ml.input")
        .transform(ErrorMessage.class, (ErrorMessage m) -> {
                Message originalMessage = ((MessageHandlingException)m.getPayload()).getFailedMessage();
                return MessageBuilder.withPayload(originalMessage.getHeaders().get(HEADER_MODEL, HomeModel.class))
                         .copyHeaders(originalMessage.getHeaders())
                         .build();
                  })
        .enrich(e -> e.propertyFunction("skipMLCall", m -> true))
        .channel("enrich.ifMLCallNeeded.input");
}
```

Behind the `ifMLCallRequiredEnricher` the following flow can be found:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow processIfMLCallRequiredFlow() {
    return flow -> flow.channel("enrich.ifMLCallNeeded.input")
            .route(ifMLCallRequired(), routeToMLGatewayOrBypassCall())
            .channel("enrich.ifMLCallNeeded.output");
}
```

The `ifMLCallRequired()` checks if the `skipMLCall` is false (in case of error it is set to true in the flow after the error channel) and it will execute the new SOAP call otherwise it will skip it.

When there isn't SOAP fault the flow will go through fine.

However when SOAP fault is thrown (i.e. the message goes through the error channel) then I get the following exception:

```
2020-05-22 10:10:48,023 ERROR com.acme.webservice.OrchestrationServiceEndpoint Thread=qtp14486859-13 MDC=16d7cc4c-c9da-449b-8bfa-504e6d81185d Error
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred in error-handling flow; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'enrich.ifMLCallNeeded.output'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=uk.co.acme.payload.request._2017._06.Message@4a5e6c, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@19d4520, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@19d4520, ws_soapAction=http://www.acme.co.uk/XRTEService/ProcessTran, id=902bd270-89d8-62e9-b00f-b69399241bd1, timestamp=1590138648017}], ...}]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:489)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.ContentEnricher$Gateway.sendAndReceiveMessage(ContentEnricher.java:481)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.ContentEnricher.handleRequestMessage(ContentEnricher.java:383)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
```

So when there is not SOAP fault then everything is fine so the channel `enrich.ifMLCallNeeded.output` has subscribers which is the next enricher, see the following log entry:

```
2020-05-24 20:37:58,819 INFO  org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel Thread=qtp14486859-10 MDC=16d7cc4c-c9da-449b-8bfa-504e6d81185d Channel 'enrich.ifMLCallNeeded.output' has 1 subscriber(s).
```

However when SOAP fault arises then the channel won't have a subscriber (I cannot find any log entry). I think it is because I am trying to hijack the flow with the error channel.
But what can I do in this case?

I'd appreciate any help as I am stuck at the moment. Thank you very much!

Regards,
V.

Comment: What you are doing should be fine; please add the complete stack trace; truncating it like that removes too much information. Also, turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration`; during initialization you should see messages like `Channel 'foo' has 1 subscriber(s)`. Also, debug logging of the message flow might help. It's also hard to help with problems like this with only snippets; the error flow can't be used to bypass logic downstream of the content enricher; instead it should return some other value to signal such.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the help (again)! So I am doing the right thing (i.e. adding the error channel to the content enricher, doing the error handling in a flow and forwarding the message to an input channel) ? The `Channel 'XXX' has 1 subscriber(s)` entries are logged on INFO level, I can see it only for  `enrich.ifMLCallNeeded.input` when SOAP fault. I wouldn't want to bypass the flow, so carrying on where the original processing (i.e. at `acmePreCompResponseValidator` but it is just a `GenericHandler` implementation) was would be fine. What should the output channel of error flow be?

Comment: I will add more info to my post! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Gary, I added more stacktrace. I had to truncate a little bit as I exceeded the limit of the post... I am happy to give more info in an answer if needed! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The error channel flow should not have an "output" channel; it must return a result of some kind to the enricher so the main flow can continue; you would then use something in the "enriched" message to decide whether or not to make the next SOAP call. You can paste the full stack trace someplace like PasteBin or a GitHib Gist.

Comment: The full stacktrace can be found here: https://gist.github.com/vhorvath001/8eb025446d6805efcb289d3b3f216bca. Could you please give me an example how to return a value from the error channel flow? I performed a silly try to remove the output channel in `processSkipML()` but it gave the same exception with a different channel name: `MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'processSkipML.channel#4'` Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is that `enrich.ifMLCallNeeded.output`? Is there really some subscriber for that channel? According your stacktrace, it looks like you have passed already an error handling in discussion. The current exception is fully not related to the `processSkipML`. You problem that `enrich.ifMLCallNeeded.output` is without subscribers.

Comment: I added an answer that shows how to properly handle exceptions on an enricher sub-flow; but, as @ArtemBilan said - the problem is on your output channel.

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan and Gary, thank you for your help! Eventually I went back to the advice solution and made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to properly handle errors on an enricher subFlow:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So61991580Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So61991580Application.class, args);
    }

    private final AtomicBoolean which = new AtomicBoolean();

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(() -> new Foo(this.which.getAndSet(!which.get()) ? "foo" : "qux"),
                    e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000)))
                .enrich(spec -> spec.requestChannel("soap1.input")
                        .errorChannel("soap1Error.input"))
                .route("payload.bar", r -> r
                        .channelMapping("good", "soap2.input")
                        .channelMapping("bad", "cleanUp.input"))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow soap1() {
        return f -> f
                .handle(Foo.class, (payload, headers) -> {
                    if (payload.getFoo().equals("foo")) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("test enrich failure");
                    }
                    payload.setBar("good");
                    return payload;
                });
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow soap2() {
        return f -> f
                .handle(Foo.class, (payload, headers) -> {
                    payload.setBaz("soap2");
                    return payload;
                })
                .channel("cleanUp.input");
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow soap1Error() {
        return f -> f.<MessagingException, Foo>transform(ex -> {
            Foo foo = (Foo) ex.getFailedMessage().getPayload();
            foo.setBar("bad");
            return foo;
        });
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow cleanUp() {
        return f -> f.log();
    }

    public static class Foo {

        private final String foo;

        private String bar;

        private String baz;

        public Foo(String foo) {
            this.foo = foo;
        }

        public String getFoo() {
            return this.foo;
        }

        public String getBar() {
            return this.bar;
        }

        public void setBar(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        public String getBaz() {
            return this.baz;
        }

        public void setBaz(String baz) {
            this.baz = baz;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo [foo=" + this.foo + ", bar=" + this.bar + ", baz=" + this.baz + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

```
GenericMessage [payload=Foo [foo=foo, bar=bad, baz=null], headers={id=e5a943c7-dcf1-47f3-436e-5d0350a1c6f5, timestamp=1590511422083}]
GenericMessage [payload=Foo [foo=qux, bar=good, baz=soap2], headers={id=a99d7ddb-2f40-f0f7-08b6-6340563e011d, timestamp=1590511427086}]
2
```

Comment: Thanks Gary! In the end I used the `advice` solution.